# UFW Block Incoming request from specific port number

Tags: linux, firewall, ufw

My server is being abused by someone with a large number of computers. I noticed they're all running on the same port, so to be clear, I'm getting incoming requests from:

```
some-ip1:3333
some-ip2:3333
some-ip3:3333
...
```

And no matter how many IPs I block individually, a new one just keeps coming back but from a new IP but from the same port number. How can I use UFW to block any incoming request from a specific port number, but from any IP address?

`ufw deny [port]` doesn't work because that blocks people from accessing MY port 3333, and `ufw deny in/out [port]` seems to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like:

```
ufw deny from 0.0.0.0 port 3333
```

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/ufw.8.html
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW#Services

Comment: Note to future readers: I edited my answer, so "second one did it" in @deRadd comment refers to the only ufw line in the answer